# Bq Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu Music app doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sd-card

-The SD-card works: I am able to read the documents which are on it, for example.
-When I call up the SD card, on the other hand, there just a series of 00000 to be seen.
-I can see the title of the music I want to play on the Music app, but nothing happens when I want to play it. The "playing time" stays at zero.
Thanks!
Richard

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and it was this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/mediascanner2/+bug/1436110 try to change the year field of the mp3 tags and see if it works, it did for me.